# ArcGIS returns "IconSymbol3DLayer failed to load" when configuring a PictureMarkerSymbol

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to add a `PictureMarkerSymbol` to a `SceneView`, but I'm getting the following error upon reloading the page:

```
[esri.views.3d.layers.graphics.Graphics3DSymbolLayer] IconSymbol3DLayer failed to load (Request for icon resource failed:
```

Here is how I'm configuring the `PictureMarkerSymbol`:

```
var source = {
    geometry: {
        type: "point",
        longitude: 86.845,
        latitude: 27.991,
        z: 5194.164
    },
    symbol: {
        type: "picture-marker",
        url: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png",
        width: 20,
        height: 20
    }
};

var flayer = new FeatureLayer({
    source: [source],
    fields: [],
    objectIdField: "ObjectID",
    geometryType: "point"
});
map.add(flayer);
```

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure a few things are covered:

1. You are saying your `objectIdField` is `ObjectID` but that does not appear in your (empty) `fields` array. You must have an entry in the `fields` array for this `field` that you're saying exists.
2. Instead of defining a symbol on feature, instead set a renderer on the FeatureLayer.

[Example code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/1hhtsjqn/)

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the code, but picture-markers still don't work, not sure what I'm doing wrong there as I am following their documentation strictly.

Comment: You might be running into a cross-domain issue. Is the image that you're trying to load on the same domain of the url of the page you're working on?

Comment: I've tried with both and the error still happens. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @gespinha if you replace the `symbol` json above with the correct syntax for picture marker symbol, like this, it should work fine for you: `symbol: { type: "picture-marker", url: "icon.png", width: "50px", height: "50px"}`

Comment: I've just tried updating the syntax, but the result is the same. Not really sure what could be causing this and the ArcGIS documentation doesn't help as well.